ValueError: called `set_weights(weights)` on layer 'conv2d_7' with a weight list of length 2, but the layer was expecting 1 weights
I'm trying to set weights on one of the layers within my model to no avail.
I've followed the solutions to similar problems online and none of them are seeming to work for me. The variable 'w' (as denoted in the code below) is of structure [numpy array, numpy array]. The first is of size(3, 3, 3, 64) and the second is of shape (64,). I want to achieve a similar functionality to that of the 'weights' kwarg in tf 2.X, but can't seem to get it working. Here's my code:
encoder = Sequential()
encoder.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', use_bias=False, input_shape=(SIZE, SIZE, 3)))
w = model.layers[0].get_weights()
encoder.layers[0].set_weights([w])
encoder.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
encoder.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', weights=model.layers[2].get_weights()))
encoder.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
encoder.add(layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', weights=model.layers[4].get_weights()))
encoder.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
encoder.summary()

And the error:
ERROR: ValueError: You called `set_weights(weights)` on layer 'conv2d_7' with 
a weight list of length 2, but the layer was expecting 1 weights.


Think about what use_bias=False is doing and how it relates to the error message.

@Dr.Snoopy Oh, I just noticed that. I was telling the layer not to include a bias term so it only expects 1 weight. Edit: I just changed it so that user_bias=True and I go this error now: ValueError: You called set_weights(weights) on layer 'conv2d_7' with a weight list of length 1, but the layer was expecting 2 weights. W is a list with 2 elements in it though so I don't know...

Try to build the layer before set weights -
encoder.layers[0].build(w.shape) and then
encoder.layers[0].set_weights([w])
